# How to display gestures from the library as a bitmap?

Tags: android, gesture, linked-list

I need to display the gesture library as a bitmap images. The code below is what I have, however it doesnt seem to work. I am getting an error on Logcat every time I run the program.

```
sStore = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures_alph);
    int i = 0;
    for (String name : sStore.getGestureEntries())
    {  
            for (Gesture gesture : sStore.getGestures(name))
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = gesture.toBitmap(mThumbnailSize, mThumbnailSize, mThumbnailInset, mPathColor);
                theList.add(i,bitmap);
                i++;
            }
    }

    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*theList.size());
    Bitmap element = theList.get(rand);
    imagetemp.setImageBitmap(element);
    gestures.addView(imagetemp);

}
```

The error I get is shown below, It says that there is nothing in the arraylist, so it is probably the for loop.

**ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8258): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8258): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.menu.sample/com.menu.sample.ImageTest}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)**

**Error Fixed**
The Library had to be loaded first.

```
if (sStore.load()){
     for (String name : sStore.getGestureEntries())      {
         for (Gesture gesture : sStore.getGestures(name))

                {
```

Comment: I fixed the error I was getting, I did not load the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error basically is trying to tell you that the list of bitmaps is empty. So, first of all, check the size of the list:

```
if( theList.size() > 0 ){
    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*theList.size());
    Bitmap element = theList.get(rand);
    imagetemp.setImageBitmap(element);
    gestures.addView(imagetemp);
}
```

And debug the first part of your code to see why your list is not being populated with the bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks Cristian. Im not sure exactly why its empty though. There must be something I am not seeing.

Comment: Have you trying using the eclipse's debugger to see what's going on in the two `for`s of your code?

Comment: I just tried the code using the debugger there, the for loops never run. They are skipped. I will go back to GestureBuilderActivity.java, and have another look. Thanks!